# Snippet of code on Coursera course

Tags: python, pandas

I am from a non-computer background and taking a course on data science on coursera. I have researched on the web for an explanation, but I am unable to find one. This is a snippet of code for which I am unable to understand anything. I do know that it is slicing columns but how is the renaming working with Gold + col[4:]
Before the code:

[image]

the code:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col[:2]=='01':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Gold' + col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:2]=='02':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Silver' + col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:2]=='03':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Bronze' + col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:1]=='№':
        df.rename(columns={col:'#' + col[1:]}, inplace=True)
```

after the code:

[image]

Comment: You are just renaming column with name contained in `col` variable

Comment: So col[:2] means from column index 0 to column index 2. That's Country column to 01! column (before the code). Is that correct? What about this, {col:'Gold' + col[4:]}. I am unable to wrap my head around this. I checked out rename online but found nothing like this.

Comment: Thank you [DavidG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5851928/davidg) for taking the trouble of editing my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The col in columns gives you each column name.
2. The col[:2] is looking at the first 2 characters of the column name to see if it's 01,02, or 03 to translate that to Gold, Silver or Bronze.
3. The .1, .2, and .3 need to be kept at the end of the column names, so the col[4:] is capturing the 4th through last characters to ensure that the appropriate ending gets tacked on to the renamed columns.

Comment: Oh ok! I completely misunderstood col[:2]. I thought it referenced the col index. I have accepted this answer.

Comment: Yeah this is why variable names are fundamental in python.  I would have name col col_name instead to specify it's a string, rather the entity of the column itself.

Comment: Definitely it would have made more sense especially for a course. I took a day to research this and then posted the question here.